# Highlight cells in a sheet based on corresponding cell values in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to highlight certain cells of a sheet based on another sheet's values.

I have two sheets in my Excel file:
"*Check*" and "*Formula*"

I would like to highlight the cells in sheet '**Check**' with red if their corresponding cells in Sheet '**Formula**' are marked as "**FAIL**".

Note: The number of columns is not static. (There is no fixed structure for number of columns. It can be 4, 5, 6 etc.)

Cells in Check sheet to be highlighted red
[image: Cells in Check sheets to be highlighted as Red]

IF FAIL appears in Formula sheet its corresponding value in other sheet should be highlighted
[image: IF FAIL appears in Formula sheet its corresponding value in other sheet should be highlighted]

Comment: What does "their corresponding cells in Sheet 'Formula'" mean? Having the same row? Based on what logic to determine if columns are "4 ,5,6"? Should the last one be named "Status"? No other columns should exist after the ones to be processed? Did you try Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Yes, having the same row. R2C1 in the 'Check' Sheet test result is present in R2C1 in the 'Formula' Sheet. Similarly, for other cells as well. No, its not necessary that the last column would be status. 

The no. of columns would vary for every dataset. I guess we would need last used column formula to extract the total columns.

Yes, I am able to perform this action using Conditional formatting but I was curious to know if the same could be performed using VBA. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then, test the code I posted and send some feedback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not prefer Conditional Formatting, please use the next VBA code. It will place the range to be processed (from ) in an array, iterate between all array elements and create a `Union` Range to be colored at the end:

```
Sub HighlightCells()
 Dim shCh As Worksheet, shF As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim rngF As Range, arrH, i As Long, j As Long, rngFAIL As Range
 
 Set shCh = Sheets("Check") 
 Set shF = Sheets("Formula")
 lastR = shCh.Range("A" & shCh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastCol = shCh.cells(1, shCh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
 
 Set rngF = shCh.Range("A2", shCh.cells(lastR, lastCol))
  rngF.Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear the previous coloring
 arrH = shF.Range("A2", shF.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value2
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrH)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrH, 2)
        If arrH(i, j) = "FAIL" Then
            Set rngFAIL = addToFAIL(rngF.cells(i, j), rngFAIL)
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 If Not rngFAIL Is Nothing Then rngFAIL.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub

Function addToFAIL(rng As Range, rngFAIL As Range) As Range
  If rngFAIL Is Nothing Then
        Set addToFAIL = rng
  Else
        Set addToFAIL = Union(rngFAIL, rng)
  End If
End Function
```

But this is not dinamic, as it is...

In order to be dinamic you can place it in an event of the "Formula" sheet, depending on how the values (FAIL) are changed... Probable, `Calculate` if the changes take places in formulas, as the sheet name let us suppose.

If the `Union` range to be returned is huge, the code speed may be significantly decreasing, but even in such a case the situation can be handled creating (number) limitations of the range cells and color the necessary cells in steps.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Fane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru), this can be done so easily using conditional formatting, using a simple formula:

```
 =(Formula!A1="FAIL")
```

You select all cells you want to apply this formatting and fill in that formula, as you can see in following screenshot:

[image]

In case you say "But I don't want that True, False in the second column", you don't need to: when I create conditional formatting, based on a formula, I always check my formula in a temporary helper column and delete it afterwards :-)